# Can I have the same profile in pom.xml and in profiles.xml?

Tags: maven-2

This is my `pom.xml` (portion of it):

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>production</id>
    ...
  </profile>
</profile>
```

This is my `profiles.xml`:

```
<profilesXml>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>production</id>
      ...
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</profilesXml>
```

Maven says:

```
[WARNING] Overriding profile: 'production' (source: pom) with
new instance from source: profiles.xml
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can. But the warning message is pretty clear: the profile from the external file will override the one from the pom.

PS: As a side note, I really wonder why you're "playing" with the `profiles.xml` which is deprecated and [removed from Maven 3](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-profiles.xml). That's just a dead feature.

Comment: @FaZend.com: By the way, the common way of recognizing a good answer is upvoting it ;) (see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting).